# why does my react hooks reset to its default values after doing what it's suppose to do?

Tags: reactjs

I rebuild the code taking away the set states from the immediate call. after calling the geographic search function my function does everything it is supposed too. After that though the hooks refresh again to the usestates initial values.  I've been on this for 2 days now so i thought it would be okay to ask for help. I don't think its nay external page as everything goes right up until the page refreshes and all the hooks are set to default. its weird because my navbar function works fine. Apologies for those who have already looked at this.

the url to the repository:https://github.com/JonathanDaboush/realtyKingFrontend.git

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
    import { flushSync } from 'react-dom';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { default as AreaW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/areaMainComponent.jsx";
    import { default as CityW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/cityMainComponent.jsx";
    import { default  as CountryW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/countryMainComponent.jsx";
    import { default as NeighborhoodW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/neighborhoodMainComponent.jsx";
    import { default as RegionW} from "../WriteFolder/geographicMainComponents/regionMainComponent.jsx";
    import { NavBar } from "../Navbar/navbar.jsx";
    import  {MenuList}  from "./MenuList.jsx";
    import GeographicLocationSearch from "./geographicSearchBar.jsx";
    import  NewObject  from "./newObject.jsx";
    import { ThemeProvider } from "react-bootstrap";
    function Menu(props){
       
        
            
        let [supra,setSupra]=useState([]);
        let [options,setOptions]=useState([]);
        let [searchBar,setSearchBar]=useState([{locations:["country","region","area","city","neighborhood"]}]);
        let [category,setCategory]=useState('');
        let [value,setValue]=useState('');
      
        
        let handleSearchBar=(value)=>{
    
            if(value.category==='country'){
                setCategory((category)=>{let newValue='region';console.log(newValue);return newValue;});
             
             }
              setOptions((options)=>{let newValue=value.kids;console.log(newValue);return newValue;}); 
             setSupra((supra)=>{let newValue=value;console.log(newValue);return newValue;});
              getChildren(value.category+"/getById/"+value.id);
       
    
            } 
            
            let handleNavBar=(value)=>{
                    setCategory((category)=>{let newValue=value;console.log(newValue);return newValue;});
                   setSupra((supra)=>{let newValue=[];console.log(newValue);return newValue;});
                    getChildren(category);
                 
            }
            const getChildren=(value)=>{
               
                let res=axios.get('http://localhost:8080/'+value)
                    .then
                    (  
                        
                        function(res){
                            let list=res.data;
                        if(list.length===0){
                        }
                        else{
                                if(list[0]!==undefined){
                                    setOptions(options=>{let newValue=list;console.log(newValue);return newValue;});
                                }
                            
                            }
                        })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                    
    
                    
                
            }
            
                useEffect(() => { 
                    if(category===''){
                        category='country';
                    }
                            }
                    , [value]);
     
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <NavBar content={searchBar} handleNavBar={handleNavBar} />
                </div>
                <div>
                { /*this is the call */}
                   <GeographicLocationSearch handleSearchBar={handleSearchBar}/>
                
                    <NewObject {...supra}/>
               
                     <MenuList Items={options} kind={category}/>
                </div>
                   
               
            </div>
            
        );
    }
    
    export default Menu;
```

Comment: Format the code before posting it

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `useEffect` has `value` in it's dependency array.

This means that if you call `setValue`, that effect will be rerun. If that's not what you want, you can change the dependency array from `[value]` to `[]` and it will only run once when the component mounts.

You're making a call to `setValue` in the `handleSearchBar` callback, so when that callback function is called it will fire that effect again.